# Java regular expression and "greedy" or early search for slash

Tags: java, regex

```
Text:
123/444_ab/alphanum/alphanum/alphanum.sss
256/333_123/alphanum/alphanum.fff
777/999_abcde/alphanum.ggg
```

I want two groups.

1. first group matches: 123,256, and 77
2. second group matches: 444_ab, 333_123, and 999_abcde.

The problems is any regexp I come up with is including extra slashes for the second group. e.g.333_123/alphanum

```
ex. 
(\\d{3})/\\d{3}_.+)/.+[.].+
```

It should be just give first two groups with a following slash.

Comment: Just use: `(?m)^(\\d{3})/(\\d{3}_[^/]+)` or check this demo link: https://regex101.com/r/QhusAW/1

Comment: @anubhava I have never seen ^/ used before especially with (?m). Any explanation helpful.

Comment: *"Anything that is not a forward slash ..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex with `MULTILINE` mode:

```
(?m)^(\\d{3})/(\\d{3}_[^/]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QhusAW/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?m)`: Enable inline MULTILINE mode so that `^` matches start of each line
- `^`: Start of line
- `(\\d{3})`: First capture group to match 3 digits
- `/`: Match a `/`
- `(\\d{3}_[^/]+)`: Second capture group to match 3 digits then `_` then 1 or more of any character that is not a `/`

Answer (score 4):

As an aside, a requirement like this can also easily be handled by any "split by string" function.  Split on `'/'` to obtain an array of values and go from there ...

I find that this is often much easier to read, and to debug, than "regular-expression chicken scratches," when the data has a format such as what you show here.  It will also "obviously" show what should happen when the data contains 5, 4, or 3 groups as you demonstrate in your post, and it will work for any number of groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(.*?)\/(.*?)\/.*
```

This regular expression should do the trick.

Comment: Be aware that in order for the java `Pattern`/`Matcher` classes to work, the pattern has to match the whole string, so you'll need to add `.*` behind your pattern so the "rest" has some place to go. Otherwise the `Matcher` will not match.

Answer (score 0):

Use `*?` for a non-greedy match: `^(.*?)/(.*?)/.*`.

`.*?` will match only as few characters as necessary for the whole expression to match.

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a = "123/444_ab/alphanum/alphanum/alphanum.sss";
        String b = "256/333_123/alphanum/alphanum.fff";
        String c = "777/999_abcde/alphanum.ggg";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)/(.*?)/.*");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("a:");
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        } else {
            System.out.println("'a' doesn't match.");
        }

        m = p.matcher(b);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("b:");
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        } else {
            System.out.println("'b' doesn't match.");
        }

        m = p.matcher(c);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("c:");
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        } else {
            System.out.println("'c' doesn't match.");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a:
123
444_ab
b:
256
333_123
c:
777
999_abcde
```